# Creating a Numpy structure scalar instead of array

Tags: python, numpy

I just discovered Numpy structured arrays and I find them to be quite powerful. The natural question arises in my mind: How in the world do I create a Numpy structure scalar. Let me show you what I mean. Let's say I want a structure containing some data:

```
import numpy as np
dtype = np.dtype([('a', np.float_), ('b', np.int_)])
ar = np.array((0.5, 1), dtype=dtype)
ar['a']
```

This gives me `array(0.5)` instead of `0.5`. On the other hand, if I do this:

```
import numpy as np
dtype = np.dtype([('a', np.float_), ('b', np.int_)])
ar = np.array([(0.5, 1)], dtype=dtype)
ar[0]['a']
```

I get `0.5`, just like I want. Which means that `ar[0]` isn't an array, but a scalar. Is it possible to create a structured scalar in a way more elegant than the one I've described?

Comment: Do you mean [scalar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/238045) when you write [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: ar[()]` on a 0d array produces the same thing as `ar[0]` for a 1d.

Comment: @kazemakase Yes. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @hpaulj I was more interested in a way that didn't require indexing and produced a structure directly, but seems that isn't possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Singleton isn't quite the right term, but I get what you want.

```
arr = np.array((0.5, 1), dtype=dtype)
```

Creates a 0d, single element array of this dtype. Check its dtype and shape.

`arr.item()` returns a tuple `(0.5, 1)`.  Aso test `arr[()]` and `arr.tolist()`.

`np.float64(0.5)` creates a float with a numpy wrapper. It is similar to, but not exactly the same as `np.array(0.5)`. Their methods diff some.

I don't know anything similar with a compound dtype.

---

```
In [123]: dt = np.dtype('i,f,U10')
In [124]: dt
Out[124]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
In [125]: arr = np.array((1,2,3),dtype=dt)
In [126]: arr
Out[126]: 
array((1,  2., '3'),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
In [127]: arr.shape
Out[127]: ()
```

`arr` is a 0d 1 element array.  It can be indexed with:

```
In [128]: arr[()]
Out[128]: (1,  2., '3')
In [129]: type(_)
Out[129]: numpy.void
```

This indexing produces a `np.void` object.  Doing the same thing on a 0d float array would produce a `np.float` object.

But you can't use `np.void((1,2,3), dtype=dt)` to directly create such an object (in contrast to `np.float(12.34)`).

`item` is the normal way of extracting a 'scalar' from an array.  Here it returns a tuple, the same sort of object that we used as input to create `arr`:

```
In [131]: arr.item()
Out[131]: (1, 2.0, '3')
In [132]: type(_)
Out[132]: tuple
```

`np.asscalar(arr)` returns the same tuple.

One difference between the `np.void` object and the tuple, is that it can still be indexed with the field name, `arr[()]['f0']`, whereas the tuple has to be indexed by number `arr.item()[0]`.  The `void` still has a `dtype`, while the tuple doesn't.

`fromrecords` makes a `recarray`.  This is similar to a structured array, but allows us to access fields as attributes.  It may actually be an older class, that has been merged to into `numpy`, hence the `np.rec` prefix.  Mostly we use structured arrays, though `np.rec` still has some convenience functions. (actually in `numpy.lib.recfunctions`):

```
In [133]: res = np.rec.fromrecords((1,2,3), dt)
In [134]: res
Out[134]: 
rec.array((1,  2., '3'), 
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
In [135]: res.f0
Out[135]: array(1, dtype=int32)
In [136]: res.item()
Out[136]: (1, 2.0, '3')
In [137]: type(_)
Out[137]: tuple
In [138]: res[()]
Out[138]: (1, 2.0, '3')
In [139]: type(_)
Out[139]: numpy.record
```

So this produced a `np.record` instead of a `np.void`.  But that's just a subclass:

```
In [143]: numpy.record.__mro__
Out[143]: (numpy.record, numpy.void, numpy.flexible, numpy.generic, object)
```

---

Accessing a structured array by field name gives an array of the corresponding dtype (and same shape)

```
In [145]: arr['f1']
Out[145]: array(2.0, dtype=float32)
In [146]: arr[()]['f1']
Out[146]: 2.0
In [147]: type(_)
Out[147]: numpy.float32
```

`Out[146]` could also be created with `np.float32(2.0)`.

---

Checking my comment on the `ar[0]` for the 1d array:

```
In [158]: arr1d = np.array([(1,2,3)], dt)
In [159]: arr1d
Out[159]: 
array([(1,  2., '3')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
In [160]: arr1d[0]
Out[160]: (1,  2., '3')
In [161]: type(_)
Out[161]: numpy.void
```

So `arr[()]` and `arr1d[0]` do the same thing for their respective sized arrays.  Likewise `arr2d[0,0]`, which can also be written as `arr2d[(0,0)]`.

Comment: Making what work?  I cover a lot in this answer.  If you have problems doing a specific task with `numba` you should ask a new question, rather than add onto a question that nothing to do with `numba`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [np.asscalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html).
In both of your cases it will be just `np.asscalar(ar['a'])`.

Also, you might find useful [np.item](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html).